# Get all metadata from an existing PDF using iText7

Tags: c#, itext, metadata, itext7

How can I retrieve all metadata stored in a PDF with iText7?

```
using (var pdfReader = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader("path-to-a-pdf-file"))
{
    var pdfDocument = new iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument(pdfReader);
    var pdfDocumentInfo = pdfDocument.GetDocumentInfo();

    // Getting basic metadata
    var author = pdfDocumentInfo.GetAuthor();
    var title = pdfDocumentInfo.GetTitle();

    // Getting everything else
    var someMetadata = pdfDocumentInfo.GetMoreInfo("need-a-key-here");
    // How to get all metadata ?
}
```

I was using this with iTextSharp but I can't figure how to do it with the new iText7.

```
using (var pdfReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader("path-to-a-pdf-file"))
{
    // Getting basic metadata
    var author = pdfReader.Info.ContainsKey("Author") ? pdfReader.Info["Author"] : null;
    var title = pdfReader.Info.ContainsKey("Title") ? pdfReader.Info["Title"] : null;

    // Getting everything else
    var metadata = pdfReader.Info;
    metadata.Remove("Author");
    metadata.Remove("Title");

    // Print metadata
    Console.WriteLine($"Author: {author}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Title: {title}");

    foreach (var line in metadata)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{line.Key}: {line.Value}");
    }
}
```

I am using version 7.1.1 of iText7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iText 7 the `PdfDocumentInfo` class unfortunately does not expose a method to retrieve the keys in the underlying dictionary.

But you can simply retrieve the Info dictionary contents by immediately accessing that dictionary from the trailer dictionary. E.g. for a `PdfDocument pdfDocument`:

```
PdfDictionary infoDictionary = pdfDocument.GetTrailer().GetAsDictionary(PdfName.Info);
foreach (PdfName key in infoDictionary.KeySet())
    Console.WriteLine($"{key}: {infoDictionary.GetAsString(key)}");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with `"UnicodeBig"`, `"UTF-8"` or `"PDF"` encoded strings.
For example, if PDF is created with Microsoft Word, then `"/Creator"` is unreadable encoded and needs to be converted:
[image]
.
iText7 has own function for that convert:
`...ToUnicodeString()`.
But it is a Method of the `PdfString` object and `PdfDictionary` value (`PdfObject`) hast to be first casted to this `PdfString` type.
Complete solution as `async`, "unbreakable" and auto-disposed function:

```cs
public static async Task<(Dictionary<string, string> MetaInfo, string Error)> GetMetaInfoAsync(string path)
{
    try
    {
        var metaInfo = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var metaInfoDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(path))
            using (var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReader))
            {
                metaInfoDict["PDF.PageCount"] = $"{pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages():D}";
                metaInfoDict["PDF.Version"] = $"{pdfDocument.GetPdfVersion()}";

                var pdfTrailer = pdfDocument.GetTrailer();
                var pdfDictInfo = pdfTrailer.GetAsDictionary(PdfName.Info);
                foreach (var pdfEntryPair in pdfDictInfo.EntrySet())
                {
                    var key = "PDF." + pdfEntryPair.Key.ToString().Substring(1);
                    string value;
                    switch (pdfEntryPair.Value)
                    {
                        case PdfString pdfString:
                            value = pdfString.ToUnicodeString();
                            break;
                        default:
                            value = pdfEntryPair.Value.ToString();
                            break;
                    }
                    metaInfoDict[key] = value;
                }
                return metaInfoDict;
            }
        });
        return (metaInfo, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached) Debugger.Break();
        return (null, ex.Message);
    }
}
```